# PHP detect screen width then change variable?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress-theming

I'm attempting to build a WordPress theme from semi-scratch (using Understraps), and I'm using an Instagram plugin that allows placement using PHP. Basically, I'd like to detect screen width then display the number of posts accordingly.

I feel like jQuery will be helpful for this, but I don't really get how to use that and PHP together in a .php doc

This:

```
    $instagram->serve_user_media( 'foo', x )
```

Grabs *x* amount of photos from *foo*'s Instagram and displays them. I've extended this to grab 16 then randomly pick 4 from those.

For example:

```
if screenWidth < 990 {
   $user_photos = $instagram->serve_user_media( 'foo', 9 );
}
```

I understand there's probably a world of errors in my code, but please try not to tear it apart too much I'm still learning, and probably could've picked an easier challenge.

**PHP:**

```
<section class="spotlight-ig">
<?php 
    $instagram = new mishaInstagram();

    $user_photos = $instagram->serve_user_media( 'foo', 16 );

        //$delimiters has to be array
    //$string has to be array

    function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

        $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
        $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
        return  $launch;
    }


    $html = '<ul>';
        //loop to pull IG photos in and split title from array.
        $lcv = rand(1,3); // loop count variable
        $n = 3;
        foreach ( $user_photos as $photo ) {

            if ($lcv++ % $n == 0) {
                $text = $photo['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node'] ['text'];
                $exploded = multiexplode(array(":","-"),$text);
                if (count($exploded) == 3)
                {
                    $keys = array_keys($exploded);
                    $i_title = $keys[1];
                    $ig_title = $exploded[$i_title];
                    $i_author = $keys[2];
                    $ig_author = $exploded[$i_author];
                }
                $html .= '<li class="ig-post"><a href="https://instagram.com/p/' . $photo['shortcode'] . '"><h2 class="title">' . $ig_title .'</h2>'; // instagram link
                $html .= '<img src="' . $photo['thumbnail_src'] . '" />'; // hi-res photo: $photo['display_url']
                $html .= '<h3 class="author">' . $ig_author .'</h3></a></li>';
                // $photo['taken_at_timestamp'] – publish date
                // $photo['dimensions']['height'] and $photo['dimensions']['width'] – original height and width
                // $photo['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text'] – caption :D
                // $photo['edge_liked_by']['count'] – number of likes
                // $photo['edge_media_to_comment']['count'] – number of comments
                // print_r( $photo ) – for more parameters
            }
        }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    echo $html;
?>

</section>
```

**SCSS:**

```
//Spotlight setup
.spotlight-ig{
  width:85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:35px 0;
  position: relative;
  &:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% + 7%);
    height: 100%;
    top: 10px;
    background: #3747B2;
    z-index: -1;
    right:-10%;
  }
  ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2em 5em;
  -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(150px, 1fr))[auto-fit];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  }
  .ig-post{
    a{
      color: white!important;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      width:80%;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .author{
      text-align:right;
      font-size:1.5em;
    }
    h2{
      filter: brightness(1.5);
      font-size:1.6em;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      width: 84%;
      margin: 0 0 0 16%;
      text-transform: capitalize;

    }
    img{
      margin:10px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    &:nth-child(1) img{
          box-shadow: -7px 7px #888;
        }
    &:nth-child(2) img{
          box-shadow: -7px 7px #333;
        }
    &:nth-child(3) img{
          box-shadow: -7px 7px #f33;
        }
    &:nth-child(4) img{
          box-shadow: -7px 7px #000;
        }

  }
}
```

The IG Plugin I'm using is [Instagram Widget Shortcode](https://rudrastyh.com/plugins/instagram-widget-shortcode).

Comment: You can do it with jQuery by using .ajax() and .width()

Comment: Thanks @Tom, how would I link the jQuery to PHP though?

Comment: First you can get screen size with jquery then send the ajax request to the server with the width , where you will set cases to the corresponding screen and return response to that ajax and In ajax Success section you will  manupulate with dom and replace old variables  with new variables that you received from server.

Comment: I clearly need to do some research into Ajax, as I can't wrap my head around it. For now I'm just going to use :last-child in css to hide it when max-width=990px.